# Tensorflow summary: adding a variable which does not belong to computational graph

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorboard

I have a variable that changes with train iterations. The variable is not computed as a part of the computational graph.

Is it possible to add it to the tensorflow summary in order to visualize it together with the loss function?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, you can create summaries outside the graph.

Here is an example where the summary is created outside the graph (not as a TF op):

```
output_path = "/tmp/myTest"
summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(output_path)

for x in range(100):
   myVar = 2*x

   summary=tf.Summary()
   summary.value.add(tag='myVar', simple_value = myVar)
   summary_writer.add_summary(summary, x)

summary_writer.flush()
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have other summary, you can add new placeholder for  the variable what is not computed as a part of the computational graph.

```
...
myVar_tf = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32)
tf.summary.scalar('myVar', myVar_tf)
merged_summary = tf.summary.merge_all()
...
...
myVar = 0.1
feed_dict = { myVar_tf : myVar}
summary, step = sess.run([merged_summary, global_step],feed_dict=feed_dict)
summary_writer.add_summary(summary, step)
```

Answer (score 0):

Example for TF 2.0:

```
def write_list_toTB(list_myVar, main_directory, variable_name= "myVar"):
    output_path = os.path.join(main_directory, variable_name)
    summary_writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(output_path)

    with summary_writer.as_default():
        for i,val in enumerate(list_myVar):
            tf.summary.scalar(name=variable_name, data=val,step=i)

    summary_writer.flush()
```

then write in cmd:

```
tensorboard --logdir main_directory
```